# Laravel Installer - Stuck at Crafting Application

Tags: laravel, installation, composer-php

So many days I used to the composer create-project method to install laravel and then today I found this cool laravel installer method in the [laravel documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/installation).

I quickly ran the command `composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"` and got a success message. It also told that it installed in the directory `~\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin` rather than `~/.composer/vendor/bin`
mentioned in the documentation. I set up the PATH variable accordingly. (Anything wrong there?)

Anyways, I went to the directory of the project which I wanted to started and ran the command `laravel new master` and it gets stuck at `Crafting Application...`. I stopped it once and again started it once and its going on still. I surely don't want this cool method to work so slow. What should I do?

Additional Info:-

1. Internet speed: 1Mbps
2. OS: Windows 10
3. Processor: Intel Core i5-4440 CPU @ 3.10GHz (That's to mention if speed matters)

**UPDATE**
The process took about 10-15 minutes to finish. Isn't that too much? That didn't used to be the case with composer create-project method.

Comment: That does seem inordinately long (especially as the point of the Laravel installer is to reduce install time!). What it does, as far as I'm aware, is basically download an up-to-date version of a base Laravel install. That is, a server somewhere does `create-project` and then zips the resulting directory structure (including `vendor` directory) up. Then the Laravel installer downloads that zip and unzips it. So yeah, there are a couple of points it could be slow - your internet connection and the internet connection of the zip-hosting server.

Comment: So, all it does is download a zip instead of the directory directly? Shouldn't it make the process fast? And what about my internet speed, is it ok?

Comment: As far as I know yes just just downloads a zip - its whole purpose is to avoid the slowness caused by `composer install`, so yes it really should be making the process faster. Your internet speed seems fine to me. FYI the zip file to download is at http://cabinet.laravel.com/latest.zip and is just under 8 megabytes - so it should take just over a minute to download. Looking at the [installer source](https://github.com/laravel/installer/blob/master/src/NewCommand.php#L51), it does still have to do a few composer tasks after unzipping, but that shouldn't be too much of a big deal.

Comment: I have the same problem os OS X 10.10. have no idea

Comment: Some reasong to be slow is if you are using XDebug.

Comment: composer is pretty fast, i guess i'll just stick to using composer instead

Comment: Have you tried using the "verbose" tags to pinpoint where the most time in the process is taken? try `laravel new master -vvv`. We can help better if we know which part is taking longer than necessary.

Comment: @gandra404 Thank you, I had the process hung due to an active xdebug session in VSCode. Turned off my debug session and it finished.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to install php with Mbstring PHP Extension
Tokenizer PHP Extension ? and I think the laravel command is an alias to the actual composer command to create a new project. Try using 'composer create-project laravel/laravel [insert_project_name]' instead.